# How to enable TOTP-only authentication for SSH on Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: ssh, pam

I am trying to allow login to a server with only TOTP and I've installed `libpam-google-authenticator` and connected Google Authenticator app. Here are my relevant settings:

`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
AuthenticationMethods publickey keyboard-interactive
PubKeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
```

`/etc/pam.d/common-auth` (inserted at top)

```
auth sufficient pam_google_authenticator.so nullok
```

Now after a reload of `sshd`, I have two issues:

- The verification code is prompted first, but even if I enter it correctly, it still asks for password.
- Even if the verification code is wrong, a correct password allows login via SSH. (This is not intended - `PasswordAuthentication no` is supposed to block this)

How should I configure PAM to get things right?

Comment: Can you post your complete `pam.d/common-auth`? (ignoring comments of course)

Comment: Just so you're aware, the Google Authenticator PAM module is intended to be used as a second factor in addition to a key or password, and not as the sole means of authentication.